# Neural network not converging

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, biological-neural-network

I'm new to Neural Networks, and programming generally. I've written a neural network in java, and i'm looking at football data. I have two inputs:

1) Home team win % over n games
2) Away team win % over n games

Using 'standard statistical models' one can predict the number of goals that will occur in a match using these two numbers alone, with a reasonable degree of accuracy. However, when i attempt to train my NN to predict the number of goals, it simply doesn't converge :(

I'm using a genetic algorithm to train the network, here is the fittest individual from the first few generations with a population size of 100,000:

1) 0.1407408056662556
2) 0.13406266176967252
3) 0.13406267600215235
4) 0.1338753567259805
5) 0.13280257001618265
6) 0.13275165964860766
7) 0.1319768652096691
8) 0.13161029326238236

Now i know it looks like it is converging, but it is converging at a painfully slow rate, and i have run this multiple times over many generations and it will not go below 0.13.

I am using a feedforward neural network, with one hidden layer of 10 neurons, and one output neuron. I am using a hyperbolic tangent sigmoid function in the hidden layers, and a sigmoid function for the output layer. I have divided the number of goals by 10, to give an output between 0 and 1.

Before i began running this, i assumed that the NN would outperform simple statistical models, but it doesn't come close. My question is:

From the results you can see, does it look like there is an error in the code somewhere ?
Do i need to make a change to the architecture of the network ?
Do i need to change the network inputs/training data in some way ?

I've been trying to identify the issue for a while now, and it's driving me mental. Any adive is greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might very well be that what you get is the best that could be achieved with such a neural network configuration. There are existing NN implementations, such as the multilayer perceptron in [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/&usg=AFQjCNElLEXmSgml7SnMWAs-SojFE8bIdw). It would be better to start experimenting with those, where you have good analytical tools and confidence that the results you get are not due to an implementation error.